Is it ok to screw items to a wooden support beam in my basement?
My kid likes to basketball in his room but our basement has a lot more space. I’d like to screw the hoop into a support beam in our basement but I’m not sure if it’s safe.


Unless your children are 200 pounds each and they want to hang on the beam, I see no issue. The basket itself may weigh 5 pounds.

Yeah, the hoop weights very little. I’m worried about putting screws into a horizontal beam.

This is framing timber, screws 14Ga or finer (lower numbers) should be no problem.

That beam would carry 200 lb. children without issue.

@Jasen, a 14 gauge screw is extremely thin, so that advice is a bit odd. Maybe you meant #14? No drywall-type screw will be a problem. Heck, you could bore 1/2" lags into this beam without issue.

They call them 14 gauge here and

That's one of the most robust structural members in your home. It's designed to carry tens of thousands of pounds, without rest. It's also often installed in pairs, with sets of three or more framing nails joining them together. It's specified with substantial load overhead for safety. A few more screws won't amount to anything.
You'd only get to an area of concern if you put hundreds of drywall-type screws in it, or if you started drilling more than a few holes up to a half inch in diameter through it. (If you did need to drill small holes, keep them somewhat central in the beams height.)

I was thinking of drilling the holes near the bottom of the beam so the hoop is as low as possible (for more shooting space).

Holes up to say 1/4" aren't an issue, as far as placement. Larger ones need to be central.
